# Background processing on C# web api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm new on .NET technology and come into some problem. Currenlty i'm trying to build a REST API that handle long processing before sending the result to client.
What i'm trying to achieve is, i would like to do a background processing after receiving request from client. But, i would also like to send a response to client.

In short, it would be something like this.

Client Request -> Handled by controller ( doing some processing ) -> send response directly, ignoring the background that still running.

On Java, i can do this using Runnable Thread. How can i achieve this on C# Web API ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api can call another async method and return 200/OK response without waiting for the request to complete.

You can learn more about [async programing in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("coffee is ready");
    var toastTask = MakeToastWithButterAndJamAsync(2);

        async Task<Toast> MakeToastWithButterAndJamAsync(int number)
        {
         //Do something here.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, don't do this.

The job of an API is not to perform heavy duty, long running tasks.

You could simply let the API receive the request to perform something, then delegate that to another service. The API can then send a 200 response to show it received the request and maybe a URL to another resource which allows a user to track the progress.

The API needs to be available and responsive at all times. It needs to serve a number of users and if a number of them all request something that uses a lot of resources and takes a lot of time, chances are the API will simply go down and not serve anyone.

This is why you do not do such things in an API. Let other services do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve this using loosed coupled architecture, by introducing service bus or blob storage, once you receive request in web api you can save it to blob/service bus and return acknowlegement response from web api. From service bus/blob storage use webjob/function/ durable function app to process the message using event.